# Code to use Table and Metatable from lua to luatex

Tags: luatex, lua

The next code comes from the book "Programming in LUA 4th Edition".
Figure 20.1. A simple module for sets (section Metatables and Metamethods)
Here I only use the second code for the function Set.new

To be more precise, the code given in the book is the part understood purely as lua. My problem is in getting it to work with lualatex and understanding what changes I need to make.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document} 
\parindent=0pt  
\LuaCodeDebugOn
\luadirect{
local Set = {}
local mt = {}

function Set.new (l) 
  local set = {}
  setmetatable(set, mt)
  for _, v in ipairs(l) do set[v] = true end
  return set
end

function Set.union (a, b)
  local res = Set.new{}
  for k in pairs(a) do res[k] = true end
  for k in pairs(b) do res[k] = true end
  return res
end

function Set.intersection (a, b)
  local res = Set.new{}
  for k in pairs(a) do
    res[k] = b[k]
  end
  return res
end

function Set.tostring (set)
local l = {}    
    for e in pairs(set) do
        l[#l + 1] = tostring(e)
    end
return "{" .. table.concat(l, ", ") .. "}"
end 

return Set


  s1 = Set.new{10, 20, 30, 50}
  s2 = Set.new{30, 1}
  mt.__add = Set.union
  
  s3 = s1 + s2
  print(Set.tostring(s3))
  % mt.__mul = Set.intersection
  % print(Set.tostring((s1 + s2)*s1))          
}

\end{document}
```

In this code I tried of course to modify `Set.tostring` and use `tex.sprint`
but in all cases I only see `nil` as a result.

What I also don't understand is the `return Set` just after  `function Set.tostring (set)`  and I must admit that the use of
of metatables is quite anarchic. There are as many methods as there are examples.

The question is: how to transform this code at least to make it execute correctly and more generally what is the right way to handle metatables.

Remark : The code of `luaset.sty` on ctan is based on the code that I gave but it brings other complications and especially it does not help me to understand.

Comment: What is the code suppose to do? I just wanted to try it, but lualatex gives an error `:1: <eof> expected near 's1'.
\luadirect ... { \luacode@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.52 }`

Comment: @daleif with lua this code is supposed to give as result : `print(Set.tostring(s3))     --> {1, 10, 20, 30, 50}`but here with lualatex you have to change some lines `tex.print` instead of `print` etc .

Comment: For me your code never gets that far (I outcommented the rest), it stops and complains at the `s1` definition line. Doesn't it complain at your end?

Comment: you have `%` so tex comments, you can mess with catcodes but it is best to put lua in a file.lua and just use `\directlua{require('file')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to put larger chunks of Lua in a file to  avoid fighting TeX catcodes.

`set.lua`

```
local Set = {}
local mt = {}

function Set.new (l) 
  local set = {}
  setmetatable(set, mt)
  for _, v in ipairs(l) do set[v] = true end
  return set
end

function Set.union (a, b)
  local res = Set.new{}
  for k in pairs(a) do res[k] = true end
  for k in pairs(b) do res[k] = true end
  return res
end

function Set.intersection (a, b)
  local res = Set.new{}
  for k in pairs(a) do
    res[k] = b[k]
  end
  return res
end

function Set.tostring (set)
local l = {}    
    for e in pairs(set) do
        l[#l + 1] = tostring(e)
    end
return "{" .. table.concat(l, ", ") .. "}"
end 

mt.__add = Set.union
mt.__mul = Set.intersection
 
return Set
```

then you can use `\directlua` for the calls (I don't usually use `luacode` wrappers)

```
\documentclass{article} 


\begin{document} 
\parindent=0pt  

\directlua{Set=require('set')}

\typeout{=====}

\directlua{

  s1 = Set.new{10, 20, 30, 50}
  s2 = Set.new{30, 1}

  
  s3 = s1 + s2
  print(Set.tostring(s3))
 
  print(Set.tostring(s1*s2))  

  print(Set.tostring((s1 + s2)*s1))  
}

\typeout{=====}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
=====
{1, 20, 30, 10, 50}
{30}
{20, 50, 30, 10}
=====
```

Comment: I finally have a problem with my editor. If I compile with zsh I get the result otherwise I have no pdf and no results in .log. Finally using `tex.print` to get the pdf. Can you explain me the role of `return set`?

Comment: @AlainMatthes the code makes all the functions available in a table that it returns. in the require I saved that table as Set so could use Set.new in the later calls

Comment: Is’t the only solution?

Comment: @AlainMatthes is what the only solution? I just re-posted the code you posted in a form that `#` and `%` were safe, there are of course 1001 ways of accessing a safe `#` in tex but for muliple reason's I'd recommend having lua in lua files rather than in directlua chunks where the pre-expansion by tex makes copying off-the-shelf Lua "interesting" as you discovered.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself well. "Only solution" was referring to `return Set`. Maybe a new question is needed! I tried to search for information about `return` but every time it is only about functions. I have never encountered an example with this type of return. Is it possible to make all functions usable with another method?

Comment: @AlainMatthes you _can_ but it is anti-socal:-) you could not use a table at all and just define global functions `union` etc, but that would over-write any other package `new` function, Or instead of making `Set` a local table that you `return` you could make it a global table and return nothing.  You could load as `\directlua{require('set')}` and the table name would be fxed as `Set` not configurable by the caller.

Comment: see https://www.lua.org/pil/15.2.html where this is explained (a global table as I suggest above is described in 15.1) @AlainMatthes